# Magento: custom Module Access Data Through URL

Tags: magento-1.7, magento

I have Created Magento adminhtml Module. it is working perfectly.

http://domain.com/cmg/data  this is the module access url here there will be list of created fields in admin :

Title: Mama

subject: Foi

Message: BABA

what i need is  when user click on TITLE **MAMA** that Redirect user to full view page where he can read the information in details.

how can i do that? i saw in blogs module there is link of the tites when user click on it that redirect to the other page.

i tried to access through url  http://domain.com/cmd/data/id/8  getting 404 so what should i do?

Answer (score 1):

i would suggest you to make another action in your controller like

```
public function detailsAction()
{
    $this->loadLayout()->renderLayout();
}
```

Also create view file for details.phtml in your view

create block function

to get params id in block

```
$id = intval($this->getRequest()->getParam('id'));
```

fetch detail in function and return to view and display your detail in phtml file

hope this will sure your issue.

Comment: i guess you understood what i am looking for.. can you tell me how can i set another page access like  htttp://domain.com/cmg/data/miles code of this page will come through  file miles.phtml which is module's fronted folder. are you getting my point . is it possible to get such a solution  as well?

Comment: yes create one action in your data controller like public function milesAction()
{
    $this->loadLayout()->renderLayout();
} and you can done with that . pls acpt my ansewer and vote up so some one can utilize for future reference

Comment: ofcourse sir.. let me try this solution then i will vote up. i know it will work but let me see it works or not.. one more thing sir why don't you start chat room for magento issues so that i can easily ask my magnto problem to you.

Comment: currently i am very busy you can post it here i try to give

Comment: i just copied that function in controller and created new function in block file. public function getview(){ $id = intval($this->getRequest()->getParam('id')); } also called it on front end template  <a href="<?php echo getview();?>">view</a> but i ma not getting usch a output sir.. am i doing wrong?

Comment: getting following error:  <b>Fatal error</b>:  Call to undefined function getID() in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\design\frontend\default\horn\template\data\data.phtml   what should i do now..

Comment: getID function is not calling from phtml to your block file sir,,

Comment: @Jack Torris,sir.it would be glad for me if you will acept my answer and vote up.

Comment: hello sir, solution you gave me is not working getting fatal error.

Comment: might be you dont know how to create block and call it phtml file. pls add your full code in your post.

Comment: you are absolutely right sir.. i really don't know how to create a block..// can you explain me how to create the action  please  i copied that function in controller now what should i do?

Answer (score 1):

i got the answer..  I just created the below function in indexController file

```
public function infoAction() {

    $this->loadLayout();
        $this->getLayout()->getBlock('content')->append($this->
        getLayout()->createBlock('finder/info')     );
        $this->renderLayout();
    }
```

created Block File info.php

```
public function _prepareLayout() {
    return parent::_prepareLayout();
}
```

in frontend layout file:

```
<finder_index_info>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="core/template" name="finder" template="finder/info.phtml" />
    </reference>
</finder_index_info>
```

i got front view.

Comment: i am having one more issue can u help me?   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19094295/magento-create-custom-controller/19095130?noredirect=1#19095130